# Adding extra character space between columns in terminal printout of pandas.Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame()
df_test.at[0, "A"] = 210.621
df_test.at[0, "B"] = 1003.382
df_test.at[0, "C"] = 216.003
df_test.at[0, "DD"] = 2575.384
df_test.at[0, "DE"] = 2561.380

with pd.option_context('display.colheader_justify','left', 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', None, 'display.float_format', "{:.2f}".format):
  printstring = df_test.to_string(index=False)

print(printstring)
```

This prints:

```
 A      B       C      DD      DE
210.62 1003.38 216.00 2575.38 2561.38
```

What I would like to do, is add one (or two) characters of space extra, as spacing between the columns; so the output would be, for two characters of extra spacing:

```
 A        B         C        DD        DE
210.62   1003.38   216.00   2575.38   2561.38
```

How can I achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the display.float_format to `"{:.2f}  "`. This would add two spaces after every number.

In your example:

```py
with pd.option_context('display.colheader_justify','left', 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', None, 'display.float_format', "{:.2f}  ".format):
  printstring = df_test.to_string(index=False)

print(printstring)
```

Which prints:

```
 A        B         C        DD        DE      
210.62   1003.38   216.00   2575.38   2561.38
```